# SQLite3 BLOB Cast

Tags: sqlite, blob

I have a small iphone application that syncs with a server in this application i use sqlite3 to save the data, one of the tables has one field that's a blob (fieldName foto). To sync i need to send the data in a text file over the network, so i need to convert the blob to text.

The problem it's that i can't convert/cast the blob to text.

In the sqlite manual (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), it says that it can be done:
"To cast a BLOB value to TEXT, the sequence of bytes that make up the BLOB is interpreted as text encoded using the database encoding."

But i can't get this to work.

Query:
SELECT CAST(Foto AS TEXT) FROM myTable;

Result:
????

What I'm missing?

Comment: Found out how to get the hex representation with QUOTE.

SELECT QUOTE(Foto) FROM myTable;

Result: X'0000000000000000....'

Thanks